# How do Hogwarts candidates disappear from their muggle lives?

Tags: harry-potter

Neighbours, schools and government systems will assume a missing child if they move out of their homes to Hogwarts. How do they keep their old identities in sync with going to a place unrecognised by muggles?

Comment: They're not missing...they're in a private boarding school.

Comment: For the record, thousands of children in the UK go "missing" each year. For the most part, they're simply being moved overseas or elsewhere in the country.

Comment: "Neighbours, schools and government systems will assume a missing child" - no they won't. That's not how it works.

Answer (score 3):

Going to Hogwarts is no different from going to any other boarding school.  They disappear during the school term and reappear over the holidays; it would be easy for parents to explain that they are at a boarding school.  For example, the Dursleys made Harry tell Aunt Marge that he attended [St Brutus's Secure Centre for Incurably Criminal Boys](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/St_Brutus's_Secure_Centre_for_Incurably_Criminal_Boys).